# Terraform multiple for_each resources

Tags: terraform

I've created multiple subnets and multiple VPC endpoints using the `for_each` loop as follows:

```
### VARIABLES ###

variable "private_cidr_mask" {
  default = {
    "us-west-1a" = "10.0.1.0/24"
    "us-west-1b" = "10.0.2.0/24"
  }
}

variable "vpc_endpoints" {
  default = [
    "com.amazonaws.us-west-1.ecs-agent",
    "com.amazonaws.us-west-1.ecs-telemetry",
    "com.amazonaws.us-west-1.ecs"
  ]
}

### RESOURCES ###

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {

  for_each = var.private_cidr_mask

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  availability_zone = each.key
  cidr_block = each.value
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "vpc_endpoint" {

  for_each = toset(var.vpc_endpoints)

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
  service_name = each.value

  security_group_ids = [ aws_security_group.security_group.id ]

  private_dns_enabled = true
}
```

Now I have to assign every VPC endpoint to each of the private subnets using a `aws_vpc_endpoint_subnet_association`:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_subnet_association" "vpc_endpoint_subnet_association" {
  vpc_endpoint_id = <every endpoint>
  subnet_id = <every subnet>
}
```

How do I achieve this in Terraform? I have tried nested for_each loops without success.

Comment: The example at https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/setproduct.html#finding-combinations-for-for_each might give some useful pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `aws_vpc_endpoint` accepts a list of `subnet_ids` and I just missed it in the docs, so all I had to do was:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "vpc_endpoint" {

  for_each = toset(var.vpc_endpoints)

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
  service_name = each.value

  security_group_ids = [ aws_security_group.security_group.id ]
  subnet_ids = [ for subnet in aws_subnet.private_subnet: subnet.id ]

  private_dns_enabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the aws_vpc_endpoint_subnet_association resource creation

Have you thought about using the count command based upon Looking up the number of vpc_endpoints?

You could then have a single for each of the subnet id within it.